# Creating complex clipping path for image?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm new to fabricjs (and to Javascript development in general). I am "porting" a legacy Flex/Actionscript project and need to enable the user to create a complex clipping path for an image.

My approach in Actionscript was to use the `Actionscript` `Graphics` class using `BlendMode.ERASE` to "erase" from the yellow base rectangle (i.e. give the appearance of erasing) and then using that set of rects to create a bitmap to serve as an alpha channel for the final image (Step 3) created on the fly.

Can anyone suggest how I might accomplish a similar functionality in Fabric? It doesn't seem to support [HTML5 Canvas Blend modes](https://codepen.io/adobe/pen/nmfic) and while I see that it supports clipping paths for images, I'm not seeing how I can enable the user to interactively create a clipping path without doing lots of intersection checks to try to derive the points to create a new path on the fly.

Thanks!

---

**Step 1:** After the user has drawn a base rectangle, drag-option/alt-key enables them to draw a rectangle (the red line) which will be subtracted from the base rect.

**Step 2:** The base rect is shown with the subtraction.

**Step 3:** The base rect is used to clip or mask a section of the base image

---

Step 1

[image]

---

Step 2

[image]

---

Step 3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will Tower,

There is no easy way to do it. Here are the steps:

1. Draw 'Yellow' rectangle
2. Draw 'Red' rectangle
3. Use clipping library like [PolyBool](https://github.com/voidqk/polybooljs) for intersection and xor operations
4. Convert drawing result into the clipped path of combining rectangles
5. clip your image

I created some quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/689/). You have to click on a each button to clip. It won't clip if you will not add 2 rectangles on the canvas. This is very simple example. In order to work properly you have to draw rectangles with mouse (make them dynamic). Also, this logic is not accounting for these variations (you have to work on them as well):
[image]
For these use cases Clipping Library will return to you 2 set of results, which means different logic should be implemented.

Actual code without jQuery, FabriJs, and PolyBool libraries:

```
var imgURL = 'http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg';
var clipYellowRect = null;
var clipRedRect = null;
var pug = null;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// insert image into canvas
var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {    
    pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
        angle: 0,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 100,
        top: 50,
        scaleX: 0.5,
        scaleY: 0.5,
        clipName: 'pug',
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
};
pugImg.src = imgURL;

//draw yellow rectangle
$('#btnYellowRect').on('click', function(){
    clipYellowRect = new fabric.Rect({
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      left: 120,
      top: 60,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      fill: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.5)',
      strokeWidth: 0,
      selectable: false
  });
canvas.add(clipYellowRect);
});

//draw red rectangle
$('#btnRedRect').on('click', function(){
    clipRedRect = new fabric.Rect({
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      left: 90,
      top: 120,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      strokeWidth: 3,
      fill: 'transparent',
      stroke: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)', /* use transparent for no fill */
      strokeWidth: 0,
      selectable: false
  });

canvas.add(clipRedRect);
});

//clip
$('#btnClip').on('click', function(){
    var yellowRectRegion = getRegion(clipYellowRect);
  var redRectRegion = getRegion(clipRedRect);
  //determine inersection
  var intersectResult = PolyBool.intersect({
    regions: [yellowRectRegion],
    inverted: false
  }, {
    regions: [redRectRegion],
    inverted: false
  });

  //generate clipping path
  var xorResult = PolyBool.xor({
    regions: [yellowRectRegion],
    inverted: false
  }, {
    regions: intersectResult.regions,
    inverted: false
  });
  clipImage(xorResult.regions[0]);
});

//prepare data for clipping library
function getRegion(rect){
return [[rect.left, rect.top],
                [rect.left + rect.width, rect.top],
        [rect.left + rect.width, rect.top + rect.height],
        [rect.left, rect.top + rect.height]]
}


function clipImage(points){
     //actual clipping 
  pug.clipTo = function (ctx) {
      var scaleXTo1 = (1 / pug.scaleX);
      var scaleYTo1 = (1 / pug.scaleY);
      ctx.save();

      var ctxLeft = -( pug.width / 2 );
      var ctxTop = -( pug.height / 2 );

      ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );
      ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
      ctx.beginPath();
      console.log(points)
      ctx.moveTo(points[0][0] - pug.oCoords.tl.x, points[0][1] - pug.oCoords.tl.y);
      for (var i=1; i < points.length; i++){
      ctx.lineTo(points[i][0] - pug.oCoords.tl.x, points[i][1] - pug.oCoords.tl.y);
      }
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.restore();
      };
      clipYellowRect.remove();
        clipRedRect.remove();
      canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: That's awesome – thanks for your help! It looks like I will have to rethink some things since it looks like the clipping path doesn't scale or move when the clipped image is transformed. I'm still new at JS (and Fabric) so I have been a bit timid about combining other libs with it. I think I will look into a Node image lib (like `pngjs-image`) to create an image with alpha on the fly – this is for a desktop app in Electron so speed and security will be ok.