# FabricJS clipTo, mask except on an object

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, mask

I use "fabricjs" and I have difficulty understanding the use of clipTo.
Indeed I would like to make a mask on all my canvas but not on an object/background. Mask has an SVG shape.
**I am in version 1.7.3.**

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code. What did you do so far?

Comment: It is here : https://jsfiddle.net/6w7jo33v/22/

Comment: your example is doing what you need. Can you give more details what you don't understand?

Comment: Line 16 I want to display a background image in the canvas. But cliptTo prevents this.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't use easily clipTo with SVG. You have to modify path of the SVG and change coordinates of that path to your clipping box.
In my response [Creating complex clipping path for image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752110/creating-complex-clipping-path-for-image/41767757#41767757) for clipping you have to modify coordinates of the clipping shape.

```
var scaleXTo1 = (1 / pug.scaleX);
      var scaleYTo1 = (1 / pug.scaleY);
      ctx.save();

      var ctxLeft = -( pug.width / 2 );
      var ctxTop = -( pug.height / 2 );

      ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );
      ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
      ctx.beginPath();
      console.log(points)
      ctx.moveTo(points[0][0] - pug.oCoords.tl.x, points[0][1] - pug.oCoords.tl.y);
      for (var i=1; i < points.length; i++){
      ctx.lineTo(points[i][0] - pug.oCoords.tl.x, points[i][1] - pug.oCoords.tl.y);
      }
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.restore();
      };
```

For example, you want to clip from 100,100 to 200,200 positions. That box will be yours boundaries for clipping. You have to update your SVG path with new coordinate system which starts from 100,100 and scale your coordinates.

I would recommend overlay two canvases one if for background, and another for your manipulation. Example you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494261/7132835

Comment: Thank you for your examples have been of great help.
Last problem, when I select several objects, they disappear.
How to apply the clip to the selected group?

https://jsfiddle.net/CeeeJ/6w7jo33v/23/